# Loading an address in MIPS64

Tags: mips, mips64

This is probably a simple, obvious thing I'm just not seeing, but how do I load an address in a MIPS64 processor?  In a MIPS32 processor the following assembler pseudo-instruction:

```
la $at, LabelAddr
```

Expands into:

```
lui $at, LabelAddr[31:16]
ori $at,$at, LabelAddr[15:0]
```

Looking at the MIPS64 instruction set, I see that `lui` still loads a 16-bit immediate into the upper half of a 32-bit word.  There doesn't appear to be any kind of expanded instruction that loads an immediate anywhere into the upper area of a 64-bit word.  This seems, then, that to do the equivalent of an `la` pseudo-instruction I'd need to expand into code something like:

```
lui $at, LabelAddr[63:48]
ori $at, $at, LabelAddr[47:32]
sll $at, 16
ori $at, $at, LabelAddr[31:16]
sll $at, 16
ori $at, $at, LabelAddr[15:0]
```

This strikes me as a bit ... convoluted for something as basic as loading an address so it leaves me convinced that I've overlooked something.

What is it I've overlooked (if anything)?

Comment: This is a common problem with RISC architectures - PowerPC also takes a similar number of instructions to load a 64 bit immediate address/value. You'll probably want a macro for this.

Comment: So, in short, I haven't actually overlooked anything.  That's actually somewhat of a relief.

Comment: Probably not - there might be a slightly more succinct way of doing this on MIPS64 so if you hide it in a macro for now then you can always improve on it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you need to load **a lot** of constants, you should put it in a *constant pool* (A.K.A ["literal pool"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_pool)) near the current code and then load it by an `ld` instruction.

For example: `$s0` contains the pool's base address, and the constant you want to load is at offset 48, you can load it to `$t1` by the instruction `ld $t1, 48($s0)`

This technique is very common in [ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473c/Bgbccbdi.html), where instructions could only load a 12-bit immediate (only later versions of ARM can load 16-bit immediates with some restrictions). And it is used in [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_pool) too.

However somehow MIPS compilers still always [generate multiple instructions to load a 64-bit immediate](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5A1RsA1LIUBbEQwhLgiuVpYBKDgAYAghwDsfE/OvzimAmJbyWAKkMAPAGaZ0yAEZMhgCcABxmAGwArAAsAMxctPIAtPIeTLR%2BXMix6NGYkZ7hZiFBhhyxlqZmACJGxlJ6jNKRUqQs0oatqNIAwvz88sJiEvLcsbStBB0NjQDWdEEAdIaGZrQh0RtRhpG74U1S0a3tUp2k3VKtgiCGpFOnDaRwsEhoygAOeAyYZBQQb59vsQQMo8O9BJFwtFSJ4vgQftcIH5pqQ/HgWExiABPaQTUhvZSYFgEADyLAYOIepCwylYwG%2BKPwdmQBDwADdMNcqZh3JhkCJ4bjWuj4QwUQw8H5iJisT0MJIpHiCMQ8MohY1mGwUP1eIxJddII1UO9WXIuUkSVwrqJxJJaBrmscURcALIASQACgBlKHyYDIZDySKLaLyCC4QgkUZccakeRyj5fH7R8Z6eM6niTaaNCCvVCJoHkSgApPA5Ca4AhFYwuEIyjIqlojHYoX4/OE4lkimMzC0tgMqlMvmsjlcs48vkChV4kWYMVUiVSmVyrCt5Wq9WMOna3j8PV%2BA0QI0mvBm6QWrjJAiY4D2QbvTHINlBa3DO0OqQtNrO6TuELhJJfXLOl5BCZZljDCMiGIFN6HjfNAWTMZojTPpd14LMHhzPMCx%2BIt/gQ0sQExZQoUrLhblhBh4WIREGzOJsZVbAkiVJclKTOGk6QHTi8GZEdORRCd%2BUFRVhWJOdxUlaVsRXadJhVNUxI1bdOHQgRF0PY9TRYc1LVfW06A/L8TjOC5jAAJRdX1/UDMDL3DfBoNguME0QmCxi4VCM0wzpsJQQjCz%2BEsgRAd53mQKFvkrGtqLrJEUUYlsxLbZQOzY7tB17biFV4/j2UE7leRE%2BTyAk%2BczkXGTZXlNdFM3Csdz4XVNPgbTT1089LWSZQ7GADFCUEAyJCMg4TJ/KR3lQAB3H4osweRjAAFVoLgIMcyMPJjOC3NLFNYm89TfJmUh5irRYgiCLgQloSJbtiaIgmiTYDiOb8qQuK4bjubMPytd6zOkY69EaDlaI6kBoiAA%3D). For example to load 0xfedcba0987654321 on MIPS gcc uses

```
    li      $2,-9568256       # 0xffffffffff6e0000
    daddiu  $2,$2,23813
    dsll    $2,$2,17
    daddiu  $2,$2,-30875
    dsll    $2,$2,16
    daddiu  $2,$2,17185
```

Many other RISC architectures have more efficient ways to load an immediate so they need less instructions, but still at least 4. Maybe the instruction cache cost is lower than data cache cost in those cases, or maybe someone just don't like that idea

[Here's an example of handwritten constant pool on MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17275997/995714)

```
# load pool base address
    dla $s0, pool
foo:
# just some placeholder
    addu $t0, $t0, $t1
bar:
# load from pool
    ld $a0, pool_foo($s0)
    ld $a1, pool_bar($s0)

.section pool
# macro helper to define a pool entry
.macro ENTRY label
pool_entry_\label\(): .quad \label
.equ pool_\label\(), pool_entry_\label - pool
.endm
ENTRY foo
ENTRY bar
```

I failed to persuade any MIPS compilers to emit a literal pool but [here's a compiler-generated example on ARM](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'unsigned+mul(unsigned+n,+unsigned+m)%0A%7B%0A++++return+n*0x12345678+%2B+m*0x92360135%0A++++%2B+0xfedcba12/n+%2B+0x89674523/m%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:25.80013063357283,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:armg820,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O2',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0'),(h:compiler,i:(compiler:cl19_2015_u3_arm,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:/O2,source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM+msvc+v19.0+(WINE)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:74.19986936642718,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Answer (score 0):

> address so it leaves me convinced that I've overlooked something.
>   What is it I've overlooked (if anything)?

What you are missing is that even in Mips64 the **instruction size stays 32bit (4bytes)**. In this 32bit machine code encoding system, The 'la'  translated to 'lui' + 'ori' combination can handle a max of 32 bit value (address). There are not enough bits in the 4byte machine instruction to easily encode a 64bit address.   To deal with 64bit address, more iterations of the same (lui+ori) is used along with shifts (dsll).

Paxym

Comment: that way you need 6 instructions just to load a single value which is very inefficient if used everywhere