# Load 32-bit constant to register in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I was confused about this part while I study MIPS.

The textbook written by Professor [John L. Hennessy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_L._Hennessy) say if we get some *big* constant to load, we should

```
lui $s0, upper(big)
ori $s0, $s0, lower(big)
```

But why don't we just do

```
addi $s0, $zero, big
```

Since the registers are 32-bit, this is more strightforward, isn't it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The immediate argument passed to `addi` is only 16 bits. To load a 32-bit immediate value that is outside the range of a 16-bit value you need to do it in two goes, as in the example from your text book.

(Anticipating a further question, the reason there is no *load immediate* or *add immediate* instruction which takes a 32-bit immediate value is because the MIPS ISA uses fixed size 32-bit instructions, so there are always < 32 bits available for any instruction arguments - this is very common in RISC architectures.)

Comment: Thank you! Because of the fixed length, the immediate format leaves only 16 bit for constant, other 16 bits for the operation and register code.

Comment: Another question regarding combining "lui", "ori" and "or" to load a large constant into a register. 
1. Why would you do this rather than just computing the value with add-operations and save it into a register? 
2. Also, how do you use a constant bigger than 26 bits? A j-type instruction takes only a 26 bit constant.

Answer (score 6):

Yes registers are 32-bits but how can you specify a 32-bit number in an instruction that is 32 bits? An instruction consists of opcode and data. So, you can't squeeze an opcode + 32-bit data in a single addi.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, using *.data* and *.text*

```
.data
   word32bits: .word 0xFFFFFFFF

.text
   lw $t0, word32bits # $t0 now contains your 32 bit word.
```

Comment: You can do this, but lw is a relatively expense operation, so it's better not to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use literal pool if you need to load a lot of constants. Then each constant load costs only 1 load instruction. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17275997/995714) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6507814/995714)